# Multiplication of sparse matrix, linked list

Tags: c++

I have 2 sets of sorted linked list A and B, and i want to get product of A * B. for A it's easy since it's just a normal nested for loop. What about B? Initially i thought of haveing 3 nested for loop but since i'll be using pointers so it's impossible to use B[i][j]. any idea guys?

Comment: I would suggest not using a linked-list.  Why not use one of the standard sparse-matrix representations?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Comment: yeah but i kind of wanna challenge myself and try doing it. The only way i thought of is to store them into array first, and transfer into linked list. Kind of pointless if i do it that way? or is it the only way for me to do it? so i'll like know if you guys have better ideas

Comment: If you use linked-lists, then you will definitely be challenging yourself, because it makes matrix multiplication impossible!  (At least, impossible without effectively transferring the contents to an array, and then doing multiplication on that.)

Answer (score 0):

I sort of figured out a way to do it.

```
while (A != NULL)      //your first list
{                   
                       // store your row value and col in variables
   while (B != NULL)   // second list
   {
      if (colB == rowA) // you check if the b col is equals to a row, if yes you can
                        // start storing the values inside the 3rd link. 



    }

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how "colB==rowA" condition is necessary for storing the Sum of Product?